# How do I make my for loop print my LinkedList Queue properly

Tags: java, for-loop, linked-list, queue

I am writing this program to encode messages using a repeating sequence. I believe i got the encoding process correctly. using the toString statement before the printing for loop gives me the correct values, but when I try and run the for loop at the end it does not print every element in the list. for example when I enter "Hello" I get back "Igo" instead of the expected "Igopt". The only thing I can think of is that somehow my encoded List somehow shrinking as I run my for loop, however I created a new LinkedList print so that I would not affect the encoded List, so I'm not sure exactly why it isn't printing correctly.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Encode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Encode enc = new Encode();
        System.out.println("Please Enter String to Decode");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Encoded: " + enc.Encode(str));

    }

    public String Encode(String toEncode) {
        Queue key = new LinkedList(); // creates a key and adds the key values
        Queue clone = new LinkedList();
        key.add(1);
        key.add(2);
        key.add(3);
        key.add(4);
        key.add(5);
        LinkedList encoded = new LinkedList(); // creates a list for the encoded
        LinkedList print = new LinkedList();
        print = encoded; // values
        int ascii; // ascii value of the character
        int keyValue; // int value of the key to add to the ascii and encode the
        // characters
        char result; // sum of int values of the character and the key
        String s = ""; // initializes the String used for return value
        for (int i = 0; i < toEncode.length(); i++) {

            clone = key;
            char myChar = toEncode.charAt(i); // gets character at i
            ascii = (int) myChar; // converts character at i to an int value
            if (ascii == 32) { // ignores spaces
                continue;
            }

            else { // if character is not a space
                keyValue = (int) clone.remove();
                result = (char) (ascii + keyValue);
                encoded.add(result);
                clone.add(keyValue);

            }

        }
        System.out.println(encoded.toString()); // testing to see if encoded
                                                // properly *remove after
        // prints the elements of the encoded List
        for (int j = 0; j < encoded.size(); j++) {

            s = s + print.remove(); // gets the first value and concatenates
                                    // it to the string
        }

        return s;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have not had a chance to look through the code deeply, but before that I must ask if you have attempted to debug the program (IDE or using print statements)? This will allow you to step through and see exactly what is happening with your "Hello" input at each stage in the program.

Comment: If possible try to give expected sample output for sample input

Comment: @JackRyan, Thanks for the suggestion, I learned how to in class however I never really put the lesson to use. I just tried to debug it and I can see that my encode List IS shrinking. Along with the answer below I think I'm seeing where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only thing I can think of is that somehow my encoded List somehow shrinking as I run my for loop, however I created a new LinkedList print so that I would not affect the encoded List, so I'm not sure exactly why it isn't printing correctly.

That's exactly what's happening.

Your `LinkedList print` is not protecting anything at all, as it's just another reference to the same list, and the removals you do on that are affecting the original list.

To make it a different list with the same elements, you could create it using

```
    LinkedList print = new LinkedList(encoded);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are running into is called [aliasing](http://www.vias.org/javacourse/chap08_09.html), essentially by setting
`print = encoded` you are setting the two list pointers equal to each other. In java, this means that when you change one list, the other changes.

Answer (score 0):

change that last `for-loop` with `while-loop` everything works

```
while(!print.isEmpty()){
            s=s+print.remove();
        }
```

I'm looking into as to why `for-loop` didn't work